# QAccessibleTable::child: Invalid index in empty directory with QTableView and QFileSystemModel

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.6

I get the following console spam about an invalid index when navigating into an empty directory.  I get a slightly different message depending on which column of the parent directory was double clicked to get to the empty directory.  Double clicking on the Name column causes the first set of spam (the 1 0) when clicking anywhere in the table after entering the empty directory.  The 1 1, 1 2, 1 3 message occur if double clicking the other columns.

```
QAccessibleTable::child: Invalid index at: 1 0
Cannot creat accessible child interface for object:  QTableView(0x5651e6c1edd0)  index:  11
QAccessibleTable::child: Invalid index at: 1 0
Cannot creat accessible child interface for object:  QTableView(0x5651e6c1edd0)  index:  11
QAccessibleTable::child: Invalid index at: 1 0
Cannot creat accessible child interface for object:  QTableView(0x5651e6c1edd0)  index:  11

QAccessibleTable::child: Invalid index at: 1 1
Cannot creat accessible child interface for object:  QTableView(0x5651e6c1edd0)  index:  12
QAccessibleTable::child: Invalid index at: 1 1
Cannot creat accessible child interface for object:  QTableView(0x5651e6c1edd0)  index:  12
QAccessibleTable::child: Invalid index at: 1 1
Cannot creat accessible child interface for object:  QTableView(0x5651e6c1edd0)  index:  12

QAccessibleTable::child: Invalid index at: 1 2
Cannot creat accessible child interface for object:  QTableView(0x5651e6c1edd0)  index:  13
QAccessibleTable::child: Invalid index at: 1 2
Cannot creat accessible child interface for object:  QTableView(0x5651e6c1edd0)  index:  13
QAccessibleTable::child: Invalid index at: 1 2
Cannot creat accessible child interface for object:  QTableView(0x5651e6c1edd0)  index:  13

QAccessibleTable::child: Invalid index at: 1 3
Cannot creat accessible child interface for object:  QTableView(0x5651e6c1edd0)  index:  14
QAccessibleTable::child: Invalid index at: 1 3
Cannot creat accessible child interface for object:  QTableView(0x5651e6c1edd0)  index:  14
QAccessibleTable::child: Invalid index at: 1 3
Cannot creat accessible child interface for object:  QTableView(0x5651e6c1edd0)  index:  14
```

I've tried moving the location of the setRootIndex() call, but it didn't help.  Is there something else that is supposed to be done?

This code appears to work, but I've had random crashes related to this spam before ([PyQt5 Crash with QFileSystemModel and QSortFilterProxyModel..doing something wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791430/pyqt5-crash-with-qfilesystemmodel-and-qsortfilterproxymodel-doing-something-wro/44847653#44847653)).

```
import os, sys, tempfile
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
print(QtCore.qVersion())

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self._view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        layout.addWidget(self._view)

        self._model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self._model.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.AllDirs | QtCore.QDir.NoDot)

        self._view.setModel(self._model)
        self._view.doubleClicked.connect(self._double_clicked)

        # Create a temporary directory structure (tmpxyz/foo) starting at the location of this file
        path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        self.temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir=path)
        print('created temporary directory', self.temp_dir.name)
        foo_dir = os.path.join(self.temp_dir.name, 'foo')
        os.mkdir(foo_dir)

        self.parentIndex = self._model.setRootPath(foo_dir)
        # self._set_view_root(self.parentIndex) # Same spam whether called here or deferred to _loaded

        self._model.directoryLoaded.connect(self._loaded)

    def _set_view_root(self, source_index):
        self._view.setRootIndex(source_index)

    def _loaded(self):
        path = self._model.rootPath()
        source_index = self._model.index(path)
        self._set_view_root(source_index)
        print('_loaded', path, self._model.rowCount(self.parentIndex))

    def _double_clicked(self, index):
        info = self._model.fileInfo(index)
        absolute_path = info.absoluteFilePath()
        print('_double_clicked', absolute_path)
        if info.isDir():
            self.parentIndex = self._model.setRootPath(absolute_path)
            # self._set_view_root(self.parentIndex)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm using Python 3.6.1, PyQt5==5.8.2 On Ubuntu 17.04 in a clean virtual environment, but I get the same behaviour on base Ubuntu with Python 3.5.3 and PyQt 5.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to pyqt5.9 seems to have made the problem go away.